# NGINX shows the actual IP of the server when forwarding requests, How to prevent this?

Tags: node.js, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-server

my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default FILE

```
    location / {
    proxyredirect off;
    proxypass http://localhost:7000;
    proxyhttpversion 1.1;
    proxysetheader Upgrade $httpupgrade;
    proxysetheader Connection 'upgrade';
    proxysetheader Host $host;
    proxycachebypass $httpupgrade;
    proxy_redirect off;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "shows actual IP"? Where it shows it? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

This is the common problem of proxy servers. When you pass the request to `localhost:7000`, it comes from the current machine, so you see this machine's address as a remote address.

If you want to get a real user's address, you should pass it with an HTTP-header, for example [X-Forwarded-For](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For):

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
```

Then, on your backend, instead of getting `REMOTE_ADDR` value you can get real user's IP from `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP-header.